# How to JUNIT a java.util.Function using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like to perform a *junit* test using Mockito on the **toEntity** function.

```
    @Component
    public class MyEntityTransform {
        public Function<MyDTO , MyEntity> toEntity = new Function<MyDTO , MyEntity >() {
            @Override
            public MyEntity apply(MyDTO record) {
                return new MyEntity();
            }
        };  
    }
```

Unfortunately the **toEntity** is *NULL* when I mock the class and I don't know how I can test it correctly.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService _classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private MyEntityTransform  myEntityTransform 

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
      Mockito.when(this.myEntityTransform.toEntity.apply(Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(...);
    }   
}
```

When I RUN the JUNIT test, Mockito give me the error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at com.example.MyTest.setUp(MyTest.java:38)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>       when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>       verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use mocking here. Mocking is used, when testing A, that uses B, to provide a fake B to A. Mocking what you're testing doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to test that `Function` why is `Mockito` involved?

Comment: I am sorry, I want to use the function toEntity as a mock in another test.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Your difficulty to mock the class is because you violate the most important principle in  OOP *information hiding*. Method `apply()` (as you posted it here) is just a getter for the `toEntity` property. Either the class `MyEntityTransform` is a DTO without any logic, that this woule be OK but then it should not be mocked. Or `MyEntityTransform` contais some business logic, then nobody else should access its properties (directly).

Comment: MyEntityTransform doesn't contains any logic, I just need a method to transform a DTO to an ENTITY. So you say that I shouldn't mock this method then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using public fields, which is not a good idea. But anyway, what you want to mock is the function, not the instance of MyEntityTransform. So you would need something like

```
@InjectMocks
private MyService _classUnderTest;

@Mock // or @Spy
private MyEntityTransform myEntityTransform;

@Before
public void prepare() {
    myEntityTransform.toEntity = mock(Function.class);
}
```

But quite frankly, I wouldn't use a public field of type Function. Instead, I would use a public method:

```
public class MyEntityTransform {
    public MyEntity toEntity(MyDTO record) {
        return new MyEntity();   
    }
}
```

Then you can mock MyEntityTransform and make its toEntity method return what you want. And if you need to pass a Function doing what the method does, use a method reference:

```
collection.stream().map(myEntityTranform::toEntity)
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me realize my mistake.